# Changing the visibiliy of one DIV based on presence of another div or element

Tags: html, css

Ok, I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and not quite sure it's possible in pure CSS.

I'm trying to create a bit of custom styling on a page of FileRun links that I send to clients. Sending a bunch of subfolders of large TIFF images (I split them up to make the download manageable). Most clients can figure out that they should go into each subfolder and download them individually. However, the "download all" button appears on the main page of the link, and plenty of not so tech-savvy clients send me angry emails complaining that they hit the "download all" button, and can't open or download the 5GB zip file that FileRun creates of the entire main folder link.

An example of a page is here:

https://demo.filerun.co/wl/?id=T2Gv5oGiGMxO3welkXbaqs92fZ6meJmU

The main limitation is that FileRun is encoded in IonCube, so I **only** have access to the CSS file, so no way I can add javascript or PHP code.

I've been trying to find a way to write CSS to hide the DOWNLOAD ALL button `<a class="actionBtn">` by changing the CSS to `.actionBtn {display:none;}` in the main link page, but not any subfolders. I have found you can tell when you are in a subfolder page when there is a 2+ level breadcrumb containing a carat.

e.g. in the 'elf' [subfolder](https://demo.filerun.co/wl/?id=T2Gv5oGiGMxO3welkXbaqs92fZ6meJmU&path=elf&mode=default), this can be detected by the presence of the `>` in the breadcrumb, and the presence of `<span class="bcSep">&gt;</span>`

Is there any way to change the attribute of `actionBtn` or `right` div on the right, depending on the presence of the `<span class="bcSep">&gt;</span>` or number of elements in the breadcrumb?

The nesting order in the header div on the root page is:

```
<div class="left">
<a class="breadCrumb">xxx</a>
</div>
<div class="right">
<a class="actionBtn">DOWNLOAD ALL</a>
</div>
```

On any subfolders it is:

```
<div class="left">
<a class="breadCrumb">xxx</a>
<span class="bcSep">&gt;</span>
<a class="breadCrumb">xxx</a>
...
</div>
<div class="right">
<a class="actionBtn">DOWNLOAD ALL</a>
</div>
```

I've tried child selectors, but can't find a way to target the `actionBtn` or `right` element from the `breadCrumb` or `left` element... Any ideas or am I asking for the impossible from pure CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all three of your products (colored, samba and skaven) as well as the `DOWNLOAD ALL` anchor link have unique URLS, you can just use the `href` attribute value to only select the anchor tag on the homepage using a css [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like this:

```
a[href="http://someUniqueURL.com/"].actionBtn {
    display:none;
}
```

---

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```css
/* CSS */

a[href="https://demo.filerun.co/?module=weblinks&section=public&multidownload=1&id=T2Gv5oGiGMxO3welkXbaqs92fZ6meJmU"].actionBtn {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<p>Homepage Link</p>
<a href="https://demo.filerun.co/?module=weblinks&amp;section=public&amp;multidownload=1&amp;id=T2Gv5oGiGMxO3welkXbaqs92fZ6meJmU" class="actionBtn">Download All</a>
<hr/>
<p>Product 1</p>
<a href="https://demo.filerun.co/wl/?id=T2Gv5oGiGMxO3welkXbaqs92fZ6meJmU&amp;path=Samba%20Dancing.fbx&amp;mode=default&amp;download=1" class="actionBtn">Product 1</a>
<hr/>
<p>Product 2</p>
<a href="https://demo.filerun.co/wl/?id=T2Gv5oGiGMxO3welkXbaqs92fZ6meJmU&amp;path=Samba%20Dancing.fbx&amp;mode=default&amp;download=1" class="actionBtn">Product 2</a>
<hr/>
<p>Product 3</p>
<a href="https://demo.filerun.co/wl/?id=T2Gv5oGiGMxO3welkXbaqs92fZ6meJmU&amp;path=Skaven_Jezzail_Sniper_v3.stl&amp;mode=default&amp;download=1" class="actionBtn">Product 3</a>
<hr/>
```

Comment: YESSSSSS! That totally worked! Reading your comment I realized another difference between the main link page and subfolders was the presence of `&path=YYY` in the URL!

`.actionBtn[href*="path"] {display:none;}`
Did the opposite of what I wanted, disabling it on the subfolders, and not the main page. Then I did some digging and found the ability to use a `not` modifier here:

`.actionBtn:not([href*="path"]) {display:none;}` Totally did exactly what I needed in one line of CSS

Comment: @risottto Sweet. Using the NOT modifier is even cleaner than the above approach. Cheers!!